# Facebook Inbox with Fql

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I need to show the other participant's name and image in a `TableView` just like Facebook Inbox.
I am using this fql query to get the recipients.

```
- (void)readInbox {

    NSString *query =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT recipients,thread_id FROM unified_message where   thread_id IN (SELECT thread_id FROM unified_thread WHERE folder = 'inbox')"];

    NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    query, @"q",
                                    nil];

    FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                                              parameters:params
                                              HTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
    }];
}
```

and the result is something like this

```
data = ({
    recipients = ({
        email = "****@facebook.com";
        name = "*****";
        "user_id" = 6 * * * ;
    }, {
        email = "****@facebook.com";
        name = "******"; //This is me
        "user_id" = * * * ;
    });
    "thread_id" = "t_mid.1371470061934:11b440f1722f8fc977";
},
```

Is this correct for what i want to show?
How do I get all the other participants (other than me) using fql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will receive `JSON` data using FQL query. Parse it and store it in `Mutable Array`.

You can use the following query to obtain `name` and `id` of a user from his mailbox.

`SELECT name, uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT author_id FROM message WHERE thread_id IN (SELECT thread_id FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 0))`

Now the first index would be you. Remove it from the array if you want.